# Microsoft authentication ID

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app with a lot of users. I have now with an update decided I wanted to ask for their email. I am using Azure Mobile App Service, with microsoft authentication. Therefore I added the `wl.basic` and `wl.emails`.

I then read I could access the email by using:

```
var claimsPrincipal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
string email = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
```

I however never got to try the above because I ran into another issue. I store the users data by the `NameIdentifier` from:

```
var claimsPrincipal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
string sid = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

The issue is that the sid is changing when I add more scopes to the login. My issue is therefore is there some way I can extract an identifier that goes across this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. See this wiki post for more information about how to get stable identifiers for your users.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Understanding-User-Ids

Here is a snippet from the page which introduces the problem:

> When App Service Authentication was first released, the sid was generated based on the email of the user. This made it great for linking a user across two providers if they used the same email for google, facebook and twitter, but it meant that the sid was not stable. Someone could change their registered Facebook email and suddenly the sid would be different. This is why this wiki page was written -- to show how you could generate your own stable user ids.

The page goes on to explain how to get the stable identifiers and the options you have for doing this kind of migration.

Comment: Okay, so just to clarify: by setting an App Setting of `WEBSITE_AUTH_HIDE_DEPRECATED_SID` to `true`, would change the version to 4. The question is the old `sid` still available then or not? If it is then you could change the scope without issue. The current tests however seems to give me the issue. Is there another `ClaimType` I can use to get the old `sid` ?

Comment: For the sake of migration, I suggest not adding this app setting right now. What you can do instead is treat the "sid" claim as the legacy ID and then start using stable_sid as the new identity. If you store both values in your identity system, then over time you can migrate to the stable identifier.

Comment: Yeah okay so there is only the slow way. I cannot insert an extra scope and still find the old sid in some way?